# Two Button Self Latching Circuit

Tags: latching-relay

I have a circuit that includes a momentary button and self latching relay. The way the circuit works is pressing the button once latches the circuit on and remains on until the button is pressed again.

I would like to add a second momentary button that is also capable of latching the relay but not resetting it.

To put it simply, I want button A to turn the circuit on and off but button B to only turn it on.

Is there another relay I can add to the circuit to accomplish this?[image]

Comment: Please add a schematic of what you have.

Comment: please add a link to the relay datasheet ... not a link to seller webpage

Comment: Here is a link to the Finder relay data sheet. https://cdn.findernet.com/app/uploads/2020/09/16142415/S20EN.pdf The relay specific numbering is 20.21.9.012.0000. I also have a very old schematic of the way the circuit used to be set up. I have since simplified it to remove the SPST, SPDT and DPDT switches. Apologies if it’s not written the standard way since I’m definitely not an electrical engineer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify, the momentary button on the left is the button that latches and unlatches the circuit. The button on the right I want to also latch the circuit but not unlatch.